# PHP Curl array show only one object

Tags: php, curl

Pulling my hair out here..

My JSON output is like this:

```
Array ( 
    [total] => 1 
    [rows] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [id] => 45 
                [name] => MacBook Pro (Retina 15-inch Late 2013) 
                [asset_tag] => 3041974 
                [serial] => C02M73123455 
                ...etc...
```

How do I output only the **[asset_tag]** ?

I am using :

```
$responseArray=json_decode($results,true);
```

I have tried:

```
echo $responseArray['asset_tag'];

echo $responseArray[0]['asset_tag'];

echo $responseArray->asset_tag;
```

Thanks

Comment: can you provide full array so it will help

Comment: single access is like: echo $responseArray['rows'][0]['asset_tag'];

Comment: Please learn basics. It will save you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `foreach()`

```
foreach($responseArray['rows'] as $row){
   echo $row['asset_tag'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Sample output:- https://3v4l.org/8SmuY

Comment: Yes. The foreach loop looks fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2720970  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

To access the asset_tag of all elements:

```php
foreach ($responseArray['rows'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['asset_tag'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `asset_tag` collection like this:

```
$assertTags = array_cloumn($responseArray['row'], 'asset_tag');
```